# Sort entries by custom date in Matrix field / Super Table

Tags: matrix, order, plugin-supertable, plugin-supersort, sort

I currently have numerous Super Tables with date fields inside and I am trying to get all table items to list themselves together in date order depending on what the user inputs. I have tried using the Super Sort plugin but haven't had any luck.

Not sure if there is somewhere below where I have gone wrong or misunderstood the documentation. The plugin I am trying to use can be found [here](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort)

Does anyone know if this is possible with Super Tables or Matrix fields?

The error I'm currently getting is:

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string

```
protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())   
{
  echo $this->getAttribute($this->getAttribute(($context["object"] ?? $this->getContext($context, "object")), "tourDates", array()), "tourDate", array());
}
```

---

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7', '>=') && $code === 2 && 
strpos($message, 'should be compatible with') !== false)
{
    return;
}
parent::handleError($code, $message, $file, $line);
```

---

```
protected function displayWithErrorHandling(array $context, array 
$blocks = array())
{
    try {
        $this->doDisplay($context, $blocks);
    } catch (Twig_Error $e) {
        if (!$e->getSourceContext()) {
            $e->setSourceContext($this->getSourceContext());
        }
```

This is the code I current have:

```
{% set artists = craft.entries.section('artists') %}
{% set entries = artists | supersort('sortAs', '{ tourDates.tourDate }') %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    {% if entry.tourDates %}
        {% for row in entry.tourDates %}
            {{ row.tourDate|date("d/m/Y") }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I have also tried:

```
{% set entries = artists | supersort('sortAs', '{ tourDate }') %}
```

and

```
{% set entries = artists | supersort('sortAs', '{{ artists.tourDates.tourDate }}') %}
```

Comment: Never used Super Sort, but can you enabled devMode, then edit the original question and share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Added the rest of the error :)

Comment: Didn't a colleague of you ask this allready in this thread? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20720/sorting-supertable-field-with-supersort/20721#20721

Comment: Sadly this solution doesn't solve my issue, as you can see above I have tried all 3 examples shown in the documentation.

Comment: What about my comment in that previous thread? Looping over your entries, fetching all data you need and adding it to a new array. Sorting that new array with SuperSort and than displaying all info by looping over the new array.

Comment: I did read your comments, the solution doesn't work for me I'm afraid. If you have an example to show me maybe I have gone wrong somewhere in my loop?

Comment: As I can't copy/paste code in a comment with styling applied, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this as a workaround:
Loop over entries, fetching all data you need and adding it to an array. Sorting that array with SuperSort and than displaying all info by looping over the array.

```
{% set tourDates = [] %}
{% set artists = craft.entries.section('artists') %}
{% for artist in artists %}

    {% if artist.tourDates %}
        {% for row in artist.tourDates %}
            {% set tourDates = tourDates|merge([ {
                'tourDate' : row.tourDate|date("d/m/Y")
            } ]) %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% set tourDates = tourDates | supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.tourDate }}') %}

{% for tourDate in tourDates %}
    {{ tourDate.tourDate }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see where you're going with this. All this is doing at the moment is ordering them based on the day, so 1-31 regardless of what month it is, not the actual date itself. Do you by any chance know how to get it to display the order based on the date?

Comment: Maybe with {% tourDates = tourDates | supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.tourDate }}', SORT_LOCALE_STRING) %} ? Or you could write a Twig extension that uses usort() with a custom sort function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462778/how-to-sort-date-array-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I used the [preparse plugin](https://github.com/aelvan/Preparse-Field-Craft) to save a date value from a SuperTable field into a static field as 'yyyymmdd'. I could then sort my entries based on that static field.